# Woocommerce composite products

Tags: woocommerce, bundles

I am struggling to get composite products to display the way I want in this situation. I am also using product bundles.

Basically I want to display dumbbells for sale on a page, I need an option to either buy them individually (1kg, 2kg, 3kg... 10kg, not a problem) or two options to buy sets containing 6 (1kg-6kg) or all 10 of the individual dumbbells for a fixed price.

I have got very close using product bundles but even with the fixed price for the set it still creates a dropdown box to pick a specific dumbbell and whatever is picked has no outcome because the price is fixed. This is confusing for the customer so I just need that drop down box not to appear, any ideas on how to structure it?

I need the stock of individual dumbbells (for example the 1kg-6kg set) to each decrease by one if the set is purchased.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you post the code/setup you're using? That'll make it easier for others to answer your question.

Comment: I think Product Bundles is more appropriate for your intention to sell dumbells in "sets". But you need to share more about your set up, because I don't recall Product Bundles having any dropdowns.

Comment: Though ultimately, the best place to ask this question would be Woo support. Granted you have to have some patience because they are usually swamped and can take a while to get back to you. But ultimately, you should get

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies, apparently bundles in woocommerce arent really the traditional use of the word bundles, they are just choices and dont tie a products together (like in a bundle...)  I'd need to use a plugin forced sells but it's messy and all SKU's show up in cart and it's not compatible with composite products plugin. I found a worksround where I can just link the stock items of the bundle I wanted using an external inventory managment software we are using anyway (tradegecko) Thanks